# "Упростить" код до 1 строки

Tags: c#, .net

Есть ли способ решить следующую задачу в одну строку? или еще более компактно

Ввести с клавиатуры строку, если длина строки больше 5, то вывести подстроку до
первого пробела.

```
var str = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine(str.Length > 5 ? str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf(' ')) : "");
```

Comment: var str = Console.ReadLine(); Console.WriteLine(str.Length > 5 ? str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf(' ')) : ""); Profit

Comment: А чтобы было ещё меньше нужно заменить `str` на `s`!

Comment: Это очевидно, мне интересно если, что то на подобии синтаксического сахара, чтоб на вид было примерно так: 
`if ((string str = Console.ReadLine()).length > 5) Console.WriteLine(str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf(' ')));`

Comment: Постановка задачи такова, что не описано, что должно выводить в случае если в строке нет пробела. И что делать если строка меньше. У вас код имеет некоторое поведение, не описанное в задаче - и вы должны понимать, что при попытке упрощения у вас возможно будет другое поведение. А вы уже привыкли, что вот именно так "правильно" и "в строгом соответствии с задачей. И главное - зачем экономить на спичках? У вас этот код повторяется в каждой строке - вынесите в функцию. Код должен быть понятен при чтении,не надо экономить на читаемости пару буковок, иначе это не язык программирования а брейнфак

Comment: `if(Console.ReadLine() is string s && s.length > 5){ Console.WriteLine(s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf(' '))); }`

Comment: @AK Вопрос не в читаемости кода, мне было любопытно можно ли сделать это используя один символ прерывания строки

Comment: @Grundy, у меня интереснее решение)) То, которое с регуляркой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно замену по регулярке применить: <s>https://ideone.com/TcBhzA</s> https://ideone.com/ncoo2z

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(Console.ReadLine(), "^(?=.{6})([^ ]*)|.*", "$1"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Немного linq: <s>https://ideone.com/TkBCAq</s> https://ideone.com/MiTNWU

```
Console.WriteLine(Enumerable.Repeat(Console.ReadLine(), 1).FirstOrDefault(s => s.Length > 5)?.Split(' ')[0]);
```

Comment: по хорошему нужно `??""` :)

Comment: @Grundy, Console.WriteLine и так отработает, а если нужна именно строка, то да, можно добавить.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо @Grundy

```
if(Console.ReadLine() is string s && s.length > 5) Console.WriteLine(s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf(' ')));
```

Answer (score 1):

а как же Linq?

```
Console.WriteLine(new string(Console.ReadLine().TakeWhile((c, i)=>i < 5 || c!=' ').ToArray()));
```

Comment: На строке короче 5 символов тоже отработает. И вообще вопросе другое требуется.

Comment: @Qwertiy точно, я, как всегда, вопрос по диагонали прочитал.